# Nested struct with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nested

I'll try to ask briefly. I have a nested struct, the 1st one is for a Documents, and the 2nd one is for a Folder which should contains a several Documents, in that way:

```
 typedef struct document
 {
    char *docName;
    int  linesAmountInDoc;
    char **docContent;
 }Document;

typedef struct folder
{
    char folderName[20];
    struct document *docs;
}Folder;
```

Asumming i have already a several documents name such as : doc1 , doc2 , etc.. how can i do assignment to those documents name to the Folder?
I've tried somthing like this:

```
int i;
Folder *fold=(Folder *)malloc(sizeof(struct folder));
for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
    strcpy(fold->docs[i].docName, copyDoc->docName); //access violation
```

but it doesn't work. I get the message access violation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you `malloc`ed space for `docName`? Or you could make it a fixed size like you do for `folderName`.

Comment: Yes. I've malloced space for docName. I've  even succeeded to make a copy (doc1, doc2,...). Still, how can i do assignment for those document's name to the Folder?

Comment: Sidenote: Do not cast `void *`!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign memory to docs.... and docname - why not define docname as a char array rather than a pointer in the struct?

```
int i;
Folder *fold=(Folder *)malloc(sizeof(struct folder));

fold->docs=(document *) *malloc(size(struct document * 100));

for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
    strcpy(fold->docs[i].docName, copyDoc->docName); //access violation
```

but from comments you have done that ---  is it worth checking you have 5 (or more) documents declared

Answer (score 0):

That's because `docContent` is `null` even after `Folder *fold=(Folder *)malloc(sizeof(struct folder));`

There are several ways of fixing this, easiest being:

```
Folder *fold = (Folder *)malloc(sizeof(struct folder));
fold->docs = malloc(sizeof(struct document));
fold->docs[0] = copyDoc;
```

Really dirty fix, with no use of array.

Comment: I've found a solution. The Code in the Question was part of code in Function.  The assignment by using the command srtcpy is not good, however if i do a simple assignment outside Function in that way:

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution . by using a simple assignment outside Function by writing that way:
     numOfDocuments+=1; 
     copyDoc=CopyDocument(doc, numOfDocuments); 
     folder->docs[numOfDocuments].docName=copyDoc->docName; 
which **copyDoc** is a returning result of the Function, can contain any Document name in Pointer's Array (as a nested struct).

Anyway thanks to every one who tried to help me.